# How to use resource handler from another script

Tags: php, sockets, resources

I have opened a connection listening for sockets.

```
$address = "";
$port = "";

$socketResource = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_bind($socketResource, $address, $port);
socket_listen($socketResource);

//then there's listening and end connection logic
```

Is there a way to save this `$socketResource` and load it in another (completely separated, not included) PHP script?

*(assuming the connection would be still opened and readable)*

Comment: what do you mean, "another php script"? One that's loaded via include/require? Yes, that handle can be reused. a completely separate script that you exec() or run at a different time? No. that handle is not shareable.

Comment: I mean completely separate script. Adding the note to the question.

Comment: you can serialize the handle, but the network connection will be dead anyways when you unserialize. you can't preserve sockets between independent scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[answered by [Marc B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) in the question comments]*

you can serialize the handle, but the network connection will be dead anyways when you unserialize. you can't preserve sockets between independent scripts